# Annoying problem with arrows to navigate files

Tags: release-freya, elementary-website

I have an elementary freya that works nicely except for one VERY annoying thing.

When the the current file is highlighted and I want to get to the one next to it, when I press the right arrow,    it starts going through the files beginning at the file to the far left first instead of just going to the file next to it.

How to fix this?!?!

(The same thing happens for the left arrow ... meaning it starts from the far right)

This seems to be in Grid view only (which I use exclusively)

In the GIF below, whenever a folder is highlighted, I'm pressing either left or right to get the folder next to it. However, it jumps to different folders as you can see.  ANNOYING!!

[image: Gif of the problem]

Comment: I'm not getting this behaviour. Maybe post a video so we can see exactly what's happening? I assume you're up to date and using the default files application.

Comment: @TimothyGray Yeah I'm using the default files and I keep updating every chance I get. Check the OP. I've added a gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce it! Seems to be a grid view bug.

But I don't have enough reputation to only comment. The closest bug I've found is this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1579270

"

```
-Click some file or folder(double Click mode)
-Try moving between files with Arrow keys
-They will start moving from first file and not from the selected file.
```

"

You may improve the bug report with your observation.

Comment: One year later.. the bug still exists.. :(